# Execute multiple command lines with multiple arguments

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-3.x

I can't figure out why my command lines doesn't function. I tried

```
subprocess.Popen()` function : `Popen('C:/Test/test.exe -scan "C:/Users/Vince/test.txt" "C:/Users/Vince/test.xml"', cwd='C:/Users/Vince/Working_Directory')
```

But when I run a batch file from my Python program by using `os.system("E:/test.bat")`, it functions.

Here is the content of my batch file:

```
C:
cd Users\Vince\Working_Directory
C:\Test\test.exe -scan "C:\Users\Vince\test.txt" "C:\Users\Vince\test.xml"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be changing `/` to `\\` in `Popen` can help.

Comment: It works with `r` in front of the command line with simple \ too.